# Proof linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering how we could prove :

$ \text{Let} \ E, F, G, \text{be three finite dimensional,} \ \mathbb{K}- \text{vectorspaces}, \\ L \in \ \mathbb{L}(E,G) \ (\text{linear transformation of E into G}) \ , \mathbb{\phi} \in \ \mathbb{L}(F,G) \ \text{is surjective}. \ \text{Prove there is} \ \tilde{L} \in \ \mathbb{L}(E,F) \space \text{such as} \ L=\phi \circ \tilde{L}$

Thank you

Comment: You mean L not the set for sure?

Comment: Are these finite dimensional spaces?

Comment: @MohamadMisto Yes I mean L,

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Yes

Answer (score 1):

Choose a basis for $E$.  For each basis element of $E$, $e$, find $L(e)$.  Since $\phi$ is surjective, find $y\in F$ so that $\phi(y)=L(e)$.  Then define $\tilde{L}(e)=y$.

Comment: Thanks however I still do not see how to proceed how could I find L(E) given that I do not know L ?